# prolog: leave only the elements that are not repeated in a given list such that (a b a a a c c) and get (a b)

Tags: prolog

The way it should work is that if i find a (C,C) then its a duplicate and removed completely, if i find (a,a,a) then it removes them since we create a list and we compare the value from that list and so we have an (a) so if we put (a,a,a) its going to be a duplicate.
I've tried to code it and got to this.
First base cases:

```
adj_dups([],[]). % if list is empty, return empty list
adj_dups([X],[]). % if list contains only one element, return empty list (no duplicates).
```

And the Recursive part:

```
adj_dups([X,X|T],[X|R]):- adj_dups([X|T],R). % if the list starts with duplicates
adj_dups([X,Y|T],R):- X \= Y, adj_dups([X|T],R). % if the list doesn't start wih duplicates
```

When i try adj_dups([a,b,a,a,a,c,c],R). i get R=[aaa] while i am trying to get [a,b]

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: In your 4th clause for `adj_dups/2` you lose `Y` when you shouldn't necessarily lose it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let us call a subsequence that consists of two or more repeated elements a uniform sequence. Note that uniform sequences have a minimum length of 2. So first define what is happening if your list is too short to contain a uniform sequence

```
 adj_dups([],[]). % 1. stop clause
 adj_dups([X],[X]). % 2. stop clause
```

Next we move on to longer lists which potentially contain uniform sequences. 
1st case: the list starts with two identical elements:  Our list starts with a uniform sequence, but we do not yet know how long it will be. Thus we remove the first two identical elements and pass the rest list to rem_head/3 that will take care of removing further occurrences of these elements. rem_head/3 returns in T2 the list remaining after removing the uniform sequence at the beginning. We have to go on recursively and work on T2 (adj_dups(T2,T1)).

```
 adj_dups([X,X|T],T1):- !,rem_head(X,T,T2),adj_dups(T2,T1).
```

2nd case: Our list does not start with two identical elements: Due to the cut in the clause above, this clause is only processed if the list does not start with two identical elements.

```
  adj_dups([X|T],[X|T1]):- adj_dups(T,T1).
```

rem_head/3 removes all X's from the head of the list.
If the first element of the list is X it is removed and the rest list T is processed recursively:

```
 rem_head(X,[X|T],T1):- !, rem_head(X,T,T1).
```

If not, the list is returned:

```
 rem_head(_,T,T).
```

Comment: yes sir this is really all i wanted, thank you so much, is it possible to explain the code for me? :) i want to learn the idea